# Include two javascript code in one html tag : jsx syntax problem

Tags: reactjs

In my react component, I'm trying rendering with returning jsx code, but it's not working (syntax error) :

```
<button onClick={this.refresh} {isFetching && 'disabled'}>Refresh</button>
```

Following is working (but not what I want) :

```
<button onClick={this.refresh}>{isFetching && 'disabled'}Refresh</button>
```

Why this syntax error ? What can I do to display my Button as disabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just want to pass a boolean as the value for the `disabled` prop.

```
<button onClick={this.refresh} disabled={!!isFetching}>Refresh</button>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working with `disabled={isFetching}` But I don't understant why my first statement is not working.

Comment: Because it's not valid JSX syntax, that's simply all. Within tags, you must have an `attribute-name=` before a bracketed expression.